# Mongodb pull data from subarray

Tags: mongodb

Hi I have below mongodb collection

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53ce993639203f573671d3f5"),
"user_id" : NumberLong(51),
"buses" : [ 
    {
        "slot_id" : NumberLong(50),
        "status" : NumberLong(3),
        "bus_id" : NumberLong(8)
    }, 
    {
        "slot_id" : NumberLong(67),
        "status" : NumberLong(3),
        "bus_id" : NumberLong(12)
    }
]
}
```

i want to pull sub array where bus_id=8.
Final result i want to  be like this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53ce993639203f573671d3f5"),
"user_id" : NumberLong(51),
"buses" : [ 
    {
        "slot_id" : NumberLong(67),
        "status" : NumberLong(3),
        "bus_id" : NumberLong(12)
    }
]
}
```

When i tried with below query

```
db.collectionname.update({},{$pull: {buses: {bus_id:8}}},{multi: true})
```

I got below error in console,

```
Cannot apply $pull/$pullAll modifier to non-array
```

Can any one please suggest me how to achieve this,and also need php mongodb query also.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked fine for me for your sample document:

```
> db.bus.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53ce993639203f573671d3f5"),
    "user_id" : NumberLong(51),
    "buses" : [
        {
            "slot_id" : NumberLong(50),
            "status" : NumberLong(3),
            "bus_id" : NumberLong(8)
        },
        {
            "slot_id" : NumberLong(67),
            "status" : NumberLong(3),
            "bus_id" : NumberLong(12)
        }
    ]
}
> db.bus.update({}, { "$pull" : { "buses" : { "bus_id" : 8 } } }, { "multi" : true })
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
> db.bus.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53ce993639203f573671d3f5"),
    "user_id" : NumberLong(51),
    "buses" : [
        {
            "slot_id" : NumberLong(67),
            "status" : NumberLong(3),
            "bus_id" : NumberLong(12)
        }
    ]
}
```

The cause of the problem is that some `buses` element is not an array. What does the query

```
> db.bus.find({ "buses.0" : { "$exists" : 0}, "buses" : { "$ne" : [] } })
```

return? This query finds documents where there is no 0th element of the array and the array is not empty, so it should return documents where `buses` is not an array.

Comment: Thank you so much , Yes you are right . buses is not array , so i tried with below query i got result.     db.bus.update({'buses.bus_id': 8}, {$pull: {buses: {bus_id: 8}}},{multi: true})